# github - asks for username and pass when it pushes/pulls

Tags: authentication, github, push, pull

I have this issue, that I have to put this in every time I push or pull. I think this is new. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you had this problem before? It most probably means you got something wrong in your public key setup. Make sure to not set a pass phrase while generating your public key. Also, make sure that you first try to login to GitHub using

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

This should work without any passphrase. If it doesn't, check again the setup instructions for the operating system you are using.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using the https url. Switch over to ssh and make sure your keys are setup fine ( and if you have empty pass phrase ) you should not have to enter the username and password.

Answer (score 2):

Switch from `https` to `ssh` - instructions from GitHub's help docs are [here](https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password).